# Show Posts from Only One User

Tags: php, database, pdo

hello I have this table in my database called posts:

> 1-id 2-poster 3-Title 4-date 5-hour 6-imagem 7-desc

then I created a post:

> **id** - 1 **poster** - Gary **Title**- What is the concept of machine learning?
> **date** - 2021/05/19 hour - 4:32 PM **imagem**
> -https://www.iberdrola.com/wcorp/gc/prod/pt_BR/comunicacion/machine_learning_mult_1_res/machine_learning_746x419.jpg
> **desc**-Machine learning (in English, machine learning) is a method of
> data analysis that automates the construction of analytical models. It
> is a branch of artificial intelligence based on the idea that systems
> can learn from data, identify patterns and make decisions with minimal
> human intervention.

then I created a php file called **Index.html** that does an encoding in Pdo:

```
<?php
include_once 'con.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $result_msg_cont = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id Desc";
        $resultado_msg_cont = $conn->prepare($result_msg_cont);
        $resultado_msg_cont->execute();
        while ($row_msg_cont = $resultado_msg_cont->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $post_id =  $row_msg_cont['poster'];
            $Post_Title =  $row_msg_cont['Title'];
              $data =  $row_msg_cont['date'];
                $hora =  $row_msg_cont['hour'];
                  $desc =  $row_msg_cont['desc'];
                  $imagem =  $row_msg_cont['imagem'];
                  echo "<br><p> Posted in " . $data . " at "  . $hora."</p><br>";
echo  "<h2>  $Post_Title</h2><br>";
echo "<img src='" .$imagem.  "' class='img_posts'><br>";
echo " <br><h4 class='posts_desc'> " . $desc . "</h4><br>";
echo "poster: " . $post_id. "<br><br><hr>";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

the result was great because it really displays the Posts, but I only wanted to display the posts of just one example user:

> I just want to show Gary posts, if in case another user with another
> name example Fred if Fred posts something the post doesn't appear in
> index.php

is there any way to do this?

Comment: You're looking for a `WHERE` clause. That will let you filter your query.

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE \`poster\`='Gary'`

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer :

You will need to use where clause in query.

e.g.

```
  $result_msg_cont = "SELECT * FROM posts where poster= 'Gary' ORDER BY id Desc";
```

Long Answer :

Add poster_unique_id column in your posts table.

create one more database table named users with columns like id, unique_id, name, user_status, showhide. Use unique random string for unique_id column for each poster details.

Now display names of users (posters) with link to them with GET value.

e.g.

```
     <a href="index.php?poster=<?php echo $userdata['unique_id'];?>"> <?php echo $userdata['name']:?></a>
 // HERE USER NAME AND UNIQUEID IS FETCHED FROM  users TABLE
```

Then in your above current code, add

```
 $poster = $_GET['poster'];
 // then use query like

 $result_msg_cont = "SELECT * FROM posts where poster_unique_id = '$poster'  ORDER BY id Desc";
```

** Data sanitization etc not considered in this example.

### I didn't get your this line - then I created a php file called Index.html

is it index.php or index.html ??